# Know a Google Doc type (Sheet, Slide or document) without using Metadata, Android Google Drive Api

Tags: android, google-docs, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to create an App that opens a Drive folder and lets the user to select a file (Sheet, document or slide) and open it, using the Google Drive API, but I don't know how to identify the type of the file, I tried to use the metadata as the official demo of the API suggest, but I couldn't make it work.

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
        OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + driveId.getResourceId()));

try {
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}catch (Exception e) {

    mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/d/" + driveId.getResourceId()));

    try{
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }catch(Exception e1){

        mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/slide/d/" + driveId.getResourceId()));

    }
}
}
finish();
```

If I try to opened a document it works but if I try to open a spreadsheet it fails, because the intent is launched correctly, but the document is not found.

Is there any other way to know the document type in order to use the correct url to open? Oh how should I use correctly the metadata to open it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file type by calling getting the `DriveFile` from the `DriveId`, you can look at the [File Metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/metadata) section of the documentation for more details.

`OpenFileActivityBuilder` will fail since you're calling `startActivity` (as indicated in the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder))

> Note: you cannot use **`#startActivity`** to invoke the activity. This will fail.

Use the `IntentSender` from the builder to start the activity by calling `startIntentSenderForResult` (along with other needed callbacks)